# Transparency issues Unity5

Tags: unity

[image]I made a potion that displayed and rendered perfectly in 3DS max. When I imported it to Unity it didn’t render correctly as the transparency was all over the place. I first imported it with a png texture with a separate png map for the alphas. I then tried using a .tga and a .psd file with alpha channels set up within the file but I got the same issues happen with both file formats. Does anyone know how to fix this I cannot seem to work it out.

Comment: Which one of the screenshots is from 3DS max and which one is from Unity?

Comment: @Philipp i believe the left one is the good one, and the right one is in unity. Notice the cork on the top of the bottle

Comment: The left is max right it unity sorry forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a case of backface culling. The back of the textured thingy also may not be showing because the liquid inside is also zclipping the back side of it.

Comment: The back face culling should effect why the cork renders above everything else.

Comment: i think thats issues with the depth buffer. It is not handling transparency correctly

Comment: How do you change the depth buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Alpha value in color swatch for water material.

Keep the cork in opaque but potion and jar in transparent rendering mode. Give them different alpha value.

[image]

Comment: I tested this out on the potion that is 1 object and one thats in 3 sperate parts and it rendering in a simular way.

Comment: Select Transparent rather than Opaque in rendering mode dropdown as the image.

Comment: I also tried that and it came out with the same results.